# Selenium WebDriver can't find any elements on the page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to automate one airline web application with Selenium WebDriver, Java, Junit and with Cucumber BDD. I was able to create a simple scenario like selecting a one-way flight with departure date and then selecting a seat and then proceeding to the payment page. I was able to write all the test steps till reaching the payment page. Selenium was successful in performing actions for all the elements in all the page but was unsuccessful in performing actions for any elements in the payment page. I tried the implicit wait and explicit wait but not use. Initially when I ran the test once Selenium was able to perform actions on the Payment page and when I tried to run it again multiple times but the test fails because of "NoSuchElementException". Some of the elements to locate on the payment page are below:

```
Select choice = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'title')]")));
choice.selectByVisibleText("Mr");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'payment-passenger-first-name')]"))/input)).sendKeys("John");
```

The implicitwait i used is:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The explicitWait I used is:

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("elementlocation")));
```

Selenium is not finding any elements on the Payment page not only the above ones. I don't know exactly what's the problem is. 
Can someone provide me best solution to solve this problem?

Comment: If it's a payment page, the elements you are looking for might be in an IFRAME due to security. Have you checked for an IFRAME?

Comment: No I checked the whole payment page all the elements are not included in IFRAME.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Will you please add exception trace here? your explicitWait should have actual locator. For instance: 

`WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'title')]")));`

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are written inside an iframe tag then selenium will not find the elements until you switch to frame first.
Command to switch the frame (driver.switchto().frame(Framename))

Comment: The elements are not included in the IFRAME